# How to show an inputlabel/placeholder/label permanently?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, multi-select

I'm using the multi-select with checkboxes from material ui v4. The provided default settings display an array of 'SELECTED' values. renderValue={selected => selected.join(', ')}. However, I would like to remove this function and only display a permanent label. It seems that the display value is being tied to the value of the  component itself. Does anybody knows how to work around this?

```
  <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
    <InputLabel htmlFor="select-multiple-checkbox">Tag</InputLabel>
    <Select
      multiple
      value={personName}
      onChange={handleChange}
      input={<Input id="select-multiple-checkbox" />}
      renderValue={selected => selected.join(', ')}
      MenuProps={MenuProps}
    >
      {names.map(name => (
        <MenuItem key={name} value={name}>
          <Checkbox checked={personName.indexOf(name) > -1} />
          <ListItemText primary={name} />
        </MenuItem>
      ))}
    </Select>
  </FormControl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you saying that you don't want any indication of what the selected values are?

If so, below is one way of doing that:

```
      <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
        <InputLabel shrink={false} htmlFor="select-multiple-checkbox">
          Tag
        </InputLabel>
        <Select
          multiple
          value={personName}
          onChange={handleChange}
          input={<Input id="select-multiple-checkbox" />}
          renderValue={() => (
            <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: "&#8203;" }} />
          )}
          MenuProps={MenuProps}
        >
          {names.map(name => (
            <MenuItem key={name} value={name}>
              <Checkbox checked={personName.indexOf(name) > -1} />
              <ListItemText primary={name} />
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
```

[image: Edit Select - Only show label]

- `<InputLabel shrink={false}`

  - This prevents the label from shrinking and moving up when the Select is focused.
- `renderValue={() => (<span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: "&#8203;" }} />)}`

  - This causes a zero-width space to be rendered as the "selected values". This ensures that the height doesn't collapse (which is what happens if you just return empty string) while still allowing the label to be displayed.

Comment: Hi! Thank you! It works! Do you have many recommendations where to learn more about materialui? I'm kind of facing problems when i try to customize my own components. I find it hard to navigate through the documents. Sometimes, you have to go two props layer down in order to change something.(Padding,underline,labels,colors)

Comment: My main recommendation is to dig into the source code and gradually learn more about how the internals of Material-UI work. The most effective way to understand how to customize your own components is to understand the details of how the default styling is applied.