# <Select> Placeholder styling

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

So I'm using material-Ui on my react project, I'd like to set a placeholder that's only difference from a selected item is the color being grey instead of black

```
              <Select
                name="answer"
                value={values.answer}
                onChange={handleChange}
                onBlur={handleBlur}
                displayEmpty
                className={styles.selectEmpty}
              >
                <MenuItem
                  value=""
                  disabled
                  className={styles.selectPlaceholderText}
                >
                  Answer
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value={"1"}>1</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value={"2"}>2</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value={"3"}>3</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value={"4"}>4</MenuItem>
              </Select>
```

This approach gives me something very close to what I need, the problem is that:

- The "Answer" placeholder is there as a disabled list item, I don't even want it in the list.
- It's initially there as I want it, but it's color is black, I'd like to make it grey and styling it in `selectPlaceholderText` doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: style it with normal css https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_placeholder.asp

Comment: Well, That's your personal opinion & it's not necessarily right because I like w3schools, I like references more than tutorials

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Styling via a `className` on the `MenuItem` does not work because the default display of the selected menu item [displays its children](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.5.2/packages/material-ui/src/Select/SelectInput.js#L244). If you placed a `div` or `span` around the text within the `MenuItem`, it would work to add styling to that.

If you don't want the item in the list at all, then you want to use the [renderValue prop](https://material-ui.com/api/select/#props) to control the rendering of the selected item. In the working example below, `renderValue` is set to `undefined` when a value is selected in order to get the default behavior, but when the value is empty it renders the `Placeholder` element.

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";

const usePlaceholderStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  placeholder: {
    color: "#aaa"
  }
}));

const Placeholder = ({ children }) => {
  const classes = usePlaceholderStyles();
  return <div className={classes.placeholder}>{children}</div>;
};
export default function SimpleSelect() {
  const [answer, setAnswer] = React.useState("");

  return (
    <Select
      value={answer}
      displayEmpty
      onChange={event => setAnswer(event.target.value)}
      renderValue={
        answer !== "" ? undefined : () => <Placeholder>Answer</Placeholder>
      }
    >
      <MenuItem value={"1"}>1</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value={"2"}>2</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value={"3"}>3</MenuItem>
    </Select>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Select displayEmpty placeholder]

Related answers:

- [Material UI Multi-Select different code value and visible value - show keys instead values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55854132/material-ui-multi-select-different-code-value-and-visible-value-show-keys-inst/55854482#55854482)
- [How to show an inputlabel/placeholder/label permanently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56750577/how-to-show-an-inputlabel-placeholder-label-permanently/56760885#56760885)
- [Select with chip input not displaying the selected value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56240767/select-with-chip-input-not-displaying-the-selected-value/56241926#56241926)

Comment: Thanks for the very informative answer, it definetely pointed me in the right way and works, however, I've looked more into `renderValue` and for my case it was less code and works just as fine to use the code in my next comment and just style color in selectPlaceholder . Highly appreciate it <3

Comment: `renderValue={
                  values.answer !== ""
                    ? undefined
                    : () => (
                        <div className={styles.selectPlaceholder}>
                          Answer
                        </div>
                      )
                }`

Comment: `values.answer` since im using Formik and that handles changes

Comment: Thanks, its work perfectly in Mui V5 too, make sure put `displayEmpty` ;)

Answer (score 1):

**Try this method:**

**displayEmpty** use this props  for empty display and make sure
use one **MenuItem**  with  blank **value=""**

```
     <Select
        displayEmpty
        name="owner"
        value={formik.values.owner}
        onChange={formik.handleChange}
        inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'Case Onwer' }} >

        <MenuItem value="" disabled>
          Select Onwer
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
      </Select>
```

Answer (score -2):

I added a placeholder this way, to remove more logic. It worked as intended.

```
   <Select
        className="selection"
        labelId="selection"
        value={this.state.value}
        label="some selection"
        onChange={this.onSelectionChanged}
      >
        <option value="unset" selected disabled hidden>Placeholder</option>
        { this.getMenuItems()}
      </Select>
```